# How to swap class / id using jquery in a css list?

Tags: jquery, css, class, html-lists, swap

I have setup the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rb2Pz/4/

Basically I am trying to swap the class on a li when clicked (ie. remove the class motor and then add the class selected.

Also if I wished to use Id's instead of classes what code should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rb2Pz/5/ I'm not sure if this is what you wanted to do, check it out

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response not quite what I needed, but please refer to @bozdoz answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rb2Pz/7/).

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $(this).parents('.motor').removeClass('motor').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

If you wanted to use ids instead of classes (which you probably shouldn't in this situation), you would switch `('.motor')` with `('#motor')`, `removeClass('motor')` with `removeAttr('id')`, and then `addClass('selected')` with `attr('id','selected')`.  Again, classes are better in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, exactly what i needed. Much appreciated. Will tick answer as solved in few mins when it lets me.

Comment: lol.  Yeah, I guess stackoverflow tries to discourage fast answers. :P

Answer (score 1):

You could just:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.test').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().attr({ 'class': 'selected' });
    });
});
```

And if you wanna change for Ids you can use a diferent selector:

> $('ul#navlist li a').click();

Comment: nice one yourself.  Much cleaner than mine. :)

Comment: Thanks, mine doesn't do exactly what he want, but I figured if he just had one class all the time, I could rewrite class attribute.